# iPhone Settings Icon Graphics (Icon-Small@2x) Not Updating

Tags: iphone, icons, preferences

Has anyone ever had an issue with iPhone settings icons not updating with new graphics? I added a new Icon-Small@2x.png to my project, but when it builds to the device the settings app still uses the old graphic even though it's no longer there and even if I delete the app before installing! Note that in the simulator's setting app everything updates just fine.

What am I missing here? The exact name of the file is `Icon-Small@2x.png`, which is the exact name recommended by Apple, and I've made sure to add all my icon files to the info.plist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Clean first, and then Build.

Comment: D'oh, not sure why I didn't try that! A couple of cleans fixed it. Will accept once the time is up.